# section won't center other than the bottom area

Tags: html, css

I am using his theme called highlights from html5up.net.

I want to make this box thicker in the middle.  When I alter the code, it does in fact make it bigger, but it offsets the top section so it is not in the center.

[img]http://i63.tinypic.com/29vmkp2.png[/img]

The css code controlling the location of the element is:

```
.container {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

The number on line 109 controls the length of the section.

I do not know why when I modify that everything stays centered except the box at the top.

Comment: could you show us more of your codes? jsfiddle maybe? so we can edit.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ? 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/fdbf92722f0b46a6ad8bbdbd3784974f.png

Comment: Yes however when I tried to do that it would move the top box there to the right.

Comment: b0y which part of the code did you change to do that?